# Return SETOF conditionally in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a function that returns a set of a table conditionally. Something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_function(row table1)
IF row.field = TRUE
  RETURNS SETOF table2 AS ...
ELSE
  RETURNS SETOF table3 AS ...
END IF;
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You can't dynamically change the return type. You can return json instead.

Comment: You can return table but your both ```table2``` and ```table3``` should have same arguments. Because you should declare arguments after ```returns``` statement.

Comment: Not possible. The return clause must be static. And control statements (IF here) can only be used in the block execution (begin ... end) section. You can  define your 'table' and select the appropriate columns from your actual tables.

Comment: You can use `RETURNS SETOF record` to return a record set of an arbitrary schema. But then the schema has to be specified anytime the function is called by the caller. I.e., they must know what to expect. Without further clarity on what you actually want to do, it's hard to say, if that could help you though...

Comment: Do they both have the same (or similar) structure? If yes, you can use `returns table (...)`

Comment: The columns to be returned are the same for the two tables!